# Tokenizing input from getline

Tags: c, string, token, tokenize, strtok

I'm trying to use getline() to take input from the keyboard, store it in a string, tokenize it, then print the tokens. When I run this, I get a Segmentation Fault error on the the last iteration (the iteration that handles the last token from the input).

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

////////////////////////
// Main Method        //
////////////////////////
void main() {
    system("clear");
    int ShInUse = 1; // Represents if shell is in use

    char curpath[1024];   // holds current path to print with prompt
    char *UserCommand = NULL;
    size_t combytes = 100;
    UserCommand = (char *) malloc(combytes);
    char *tok;

    // Main loop that shell uses //
    while (ShInUse == 1) {
        getcwd(curpath, sizeof(curpath)); // Store initial working dir
        printf("gash:%s>", curpath);   // print prompt

        getline(&UserCommand, &combytes, stdin);
        tok = strtok(UserCommand, " \n");   // Tokenize input
        if (tok == NULL ) {
            printf("Enter a command.\n");
        } else {
            // Exit command //
            if (strcmp(tok, "exit") == 0) {
                ShInUse = 0;
            } else {
                while (tok != NULL ) {
                    printf("You entered a command.\n");
                    printf("tok: %s\n", tok);
                    tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    free(UserCommand);
}
```

Any ideas as to what may be causing this? Debugging isn't an option for me at the moment.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to initialize UserCommand to NULL ?

Comment: Comment out code line by line to see exactly where the segfault is occurring.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for your response. I tried that, but it still didn't work. I forgot to include my string declorations, I'll add them to my post.

Comment: @acheong87 Thanks for your response. I wasn't very detailed in my original post so I fixed it. I know that the error comes on the last iteration.

Comment: Anyone else curious what `getline()` actually looks like? This isn't C++, so I'm assuming it is hand-rolled.

Comment: @WhozCraig getline() was added to the std library in c99. (different impementation already existed)

Comment: @wildplasser It was ? then someone needs to update [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/mwiki/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=getline&button=), because it only shows up for C++ imps, and that site is supposed to cover through C99. I've never seen it before (much less used it). Time to go unravel my C99 standard doc and see what gives.

Comment: Don't confuse C and C++, they are different languages (with a common background)

Comment: @wildplasser Yeah, I'm well aware. I just never heard of it before, and now I'm truly curious.

Comment: Here's a `man` page: https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getline.3.html

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks. And I was *not* hallucinating. I was a GNU extension and is now part of POSIX, but it is *not* in the C99 *standard*. From the man-page you linked: *"Both getline() and getdelim() were originally GNU extensions. They were standardized in POSIX.1-2008."* At least I know its there on POSIX-compliant implementations now. Never knew that. thanks.

Comment: The `getline()` function was added to POSIX 2008, not C99 or C11.  See [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) for the POSIX definition.

Answer (score 3):

I tested your code with this:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *UserCommand = NULL;
    size_t combytes = 100;
    UserCommand = (char *) malloc(combytes);
    char *tok;
    while(getline(&UserCommand, &combytes, stdin) != EOF)
    {
    tok = strtok(UserCommand, " \n");    // Tokenize input
    if (tok != NULL) {
        while(tok != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, " \n");
        }
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and it works fine for all the testing I've done - including passing the source file in as input, writing quite long lines, etc, etc.

So my conclusion is that you probably have something ELSE that segfaults in your code.

Comment: +1 After reading the doc on `getline()` this code seems more than reasonable (though the `if(tok != NULL)` isn't needed). I think you're correct. The problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Mat! ..Why `getline(&UserCommand, &combytes, stdin)` in While loop. I understand OP need `getline()` one time. Where I am missing **?**

Comment: Yes, I took the existing code "as is", just to avoid "removing/adding" something that was affecting it's behaviour - although I did spot that `if` as "not needed".

Comment: I added the `while` so I didn't have to restart the program for each line of input - particularly so I could feed it some longer/more substantial input than what I could be bothered to write by hand.

Comment: I should add I expect the above code is called in some sort of loop somewhere, so it is probably "in the spirit" to add a while loop around the `getline`.

Comment: Yeah, there's a memory leak, I agree. Don't think that's the problem here tho'.

Comment: @MatsPetersson What did you use to compile? Eclipse won't take the getline() function during build (I'm using the MinGW GCC compiler with Eclipse on Windows). I also ran it on Ubuntu and that's where I'm getting the seg fault

Comment: It is a POSIX function, so probably doesn't exist in a Windows system. I'm using gcc 4.6.3 on a Linux system.

Comment: @MatsPetersson its the function doesn't exists in Windows systems then OP might get-error. But he is saying Seg-fault **?**

Comment: Yes, so the segfault is most likely caused by some of the 80% of the code that isn't posted here. As per usual statistics for these sort of things.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I did some more testing and the seg fault occurs when there are no words left in the string and strtok tries to find another word. For example, if I type in two words, and only execute strtok twice, the seg fault doesn't occur. If I execute strtok a third time, it does. I'm not exactly sure why this is so I don't think strtok is the best option for me. Does anyone know of any other good ways to tokenize strings in C?

Comment: Can you please post the complete program [or better, a cut down version, but complete enough to run and actually show the problem]. As I said, I have tested the above code fairly extensively, and it doesn't segfault. I have passed 450 megabytes, 54M lines, of source files through it, text files, xml files that I have in my "stackoverflow work" directory [it takes 7s when with output to /dev/null]. I have also tried specifically passing in two arguments, no crash. So, either the crash happens elsewhere, or there is something different in your system than in mine.

Comment: Please post that as past of the question.

Comment: Can you also add the exact steps for reproducing the problem with this code?

Comment: @MatsPetersson Compile and run. Once it's running, type in two or three tokens seperated with a space and then hit <ENTER> (e.g. "test string"). This is when I experience the seg fault

Comment: @MatsPetersson so when you ran it, it would just print out what you typed in and then prompt you for more input (like it's supposed to)?

Comment: Yes, it does what I expect it to do.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You were right, the seg fault is coming from somewhere else in my code. Thank you so much for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Also not an answer, just another option for programming style:

Whenever I have a tokenizing loop like yours, I prefer to construct them like this:

```
for( tok = strtok( UserCommand, " \n" );
     tok != NULL;
     tok = strtok( NULL, " \n" ) )
{
   printf( "%s\n", tok );
}
```

This keeps both `strtok()` calls close together and requires writing the `NULL` test only once.  Your way is fine, this is just another option.  Good luck!